# How to return a dictionary created in PHP into Python?

Tags: php, python, dictionary, subprocess

Due to some restrictions on what I'm allowed to use, I had to create a dictionary with arrays as values in PHP. At the end of my script, I put a return statement to return the dictionary. I now have to run a clustering algo in Python with this map. I tried to run

```
proc = subprocess.call(["php", "/path/to/file/file.php"])
```

To store the dictionary as proc. I then printed the type of proc and then the value just to have an idea if it stored the data correctly, however, the type was int, and the value was 0. (The keys in this dictionary are all strings, with arrays of integers as the values). 
Any idea on why I'm getting these return values? Or a better way to import my dictionary to Python 2.7?

Thanks!

Comment: you can just output json..... but i dont understand at all why you are doing this or in what world this is a good idea....

Comment: I am not familiar with PHP, but I suspect the script simply returns the `map` data structure which ends up getting discarded. The return value of `subprocess.call` is the return code of the process, i.e. the exit status. That is the `0`. `subprocess` doesn't magically know how to take PHP, serialize into some Python compatible format, and return the object to the python process. You have to implement that yourself. As @JoranBeasley suggested, probably you should just use JSON as your serialization format.

Answer (score 2):

I struggle to comprehend a senario where this is a good idea...but regardless

## test.php

```
<?php
$data = array("1"=>2,"3"=>5,"asd"=>22,"bob"=>"susan");
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

## python

```
>>> import subprocess,json
>>> json.loads(subprocess.check_output("php test.php",shell=True))
{u'1': 2, u'3': 5, u'bob': u'susan', u'asd': 22}
```